# Are 'far' and 'near' exchangeable in the sentence below?

Tags: grammar

Drivers must always drive as far/near to the right as possible.

Comment: Yes, your sentence has the same overall meaning regardless of whether it uses ***near*** or ***far***. But obviously that's just because it's a "pathological case" sentence which creates this paradox by juxtaposing *...as **far ON / TOWARDS the right side** as possible* with *...as **near TO** the right side*. One parsing reflects being farther away from the CENTRE, the other reflects being nearer to the RIGHT-HAND EDGE, which in the case of advice to drivers amounts to the same thing.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. Thank you.

Comment: Compare dozens of written instances of [**as near to the right as possible**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22as+near+to+the+right+as+possible%22) to *hundreds* of written instances of [**as far to the right as possible**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22as+far+to+the+right+as+possible%22). I expect ***near/far*** could be swapped in most if not all cases without affecting the meaning. But fairly obviously on average we much prefer ***far** (away from the "default" direction)* over ***near** (towards the "preferred" destination)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, they can be swapped but this is not language used in actual instructions, etc. concerning motor vehicles. Who cares if they are interchangeable if the entire sentence is "off"??

Comment: @Lambie: Obviously you don't like at least one version. But whichever one you really dislike, my previous comment contains at least dozens if not hundreds of published written instances, so obviously not everyone agrees with you. So far as I'm concerned, both versions are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To drive **as far to the right as possible** is relative to the median or middle of the road.  As far from the median or middle, in a rightward direction, as possible.

To drive **as near|close to the right as possible** is relative to the shoulder or right edge of the road. As close to the right-edge as possible.

P.S. This answer not be taken as advocating the driving advice.

Comment: Your explanation is very clear and helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think the difference you point out really works...."advocating the driving advice"?

Comment: @Lambie: I mean my answer should not be taken as me advocating the driving advice.

Comment: @TimR Ah, "the driving advice" is pretty revelatory. The "the" would not be used by a native speaker...In any case, your distinction does not work.

Comment: @Lambie I have no idea what "distinction" you're referring to or what is particularly "revelatory" about the phrase "the driving advice".The question is about near/far and so the verb chosen "keep vs drive" is a side-show.

Comment: What is revelatory is that no native English speaker would use "the driving advice". We'd use: advocate driving advice. No "the". And as near to and as far to are the same thing here in terms of the right [of a lane].

Comment: @Lambie  *The* specific driving advice in question is the instruction to drive as far to the right (or as near to the right) as possible.  And the speaker's frame of reference explains the apparent contradiction that far/near can mean the same thing here. The end result may be the same but the locative frame of reference differs.

Comment: The "the" is misplaced in: This answer [is] not [to] be taken as advocating driving advice. There is not specific thing. There is a generality.

Comment: @Lambie:.  I am perfectly willing to give driving advice, just not that advice, the advice in OP's question. So "the" is correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Drivers must always keep as far to the right as possible.**

We would not say *drive* here. You see on road signs: **keep right, keep left**.

Also, for instructions like this, I would not use "near, far, towards etc. Grammatically, they may be ok but not for an actual road sign.

For example:

> 3. What does this sign indicate? a) Drivers must **keep to the right of the divided highway**

[a high school class on driving](https://centrallakesdrivingschool.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/cl-day-10-practice-test-answers-1.pdf)

Comment: Thank you. It's good to know.

Comment: *inter alia*, North Carolina. **Department of Public Instruction:** [Drivers on mountain highways shall keep as **near** to the right as possible](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22keep+as+near+to+the+right+as+possible%22) You really are very dogmatic about what phrasings you dislike.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yep, I fine with near or far to the right. But notice: I was right about the verb **keep**. That was no so much my concern. My concern was drive instead of keep.

Comment: What I notice is that ***keep*** is more common than ***drive***, and ***far*** is more common than ***near***. But that doesn't make me think the 3 less common permutations are in any sense "incorrect" - they're just stylistic choices. There are other aspects of variance, though - for example, we don't need ***to the***, and there are a number of written instances of [*keep **as far right** as possible.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22keep+as+far+right+as+possible%22)

Comment: ... but I freely admit ***Drive** as far right as possible* is more than a little "weird"! :)

Comment: traffic + "keep as far to the right as possible" About 13,200 results (0.35 seconds) || traffic + "keep as near to the right as possible" About 4,110,000,000 results (0.75 seconds) So, my answer has far but near is more common.